# Remove warning in sqlcipher Integation in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have implemented sqlCipher in my IOS Project and when I run it shows 25 warnings like 'implicit conversion loses integer precision 'size_t' (aka 'long') to 'int''.So Please suggest How to get rid of these warnings. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `datatypes` from `int` to `long` and your warning will be not shown anymore.

for example below statement giving that warning mentioned in question,

```
 int i = [self someMethod]; //this method's return type is NSInteger
```

So it will give this warning so change it like,

```
 long i = [self someMethod];
```

Comment: actually I am using a third party project sqlcipher and there is file sqlite3.c which is having lots of warnings so Please provide any link to updated file or something